# implementing html in a html5 canvas

Tags: html, user-interface, canvas

I'm building a web UI. It is completely dynamic, and constantly moving.
The content is constantly changing by using Jquery's `ajax()`.
The interface was first built in the html5 SVG using Raphael library.
It was too slow.
I thought about using a canvas library ( like paper.js/Caat.js/etc...)
But I cannot implement html code inside a canvas ( like the `<foreign object>` tag in the SVG)
I can't just place a floating div above the canvas because the content is contently moving.
Any ideas how can I solve this?
How do I implement html code in the html5 canvas?

Comment: Why don't you just build the UI using HTML and CSS and update it when necessary? That's much simpler.

Comment: my system looks like this : [link](http://labs.hyperandroid.com/static/CAAT-Samples/demos/demo11/circles.html) but much more complex. I don't think it is the best solution to build it with html

Comment: Then you should use some canvas UI library such as canui?

Comment: if I would use that... how will I implement an embbed youtube? or a google map?

Comment: When is it going to be quicker for a browser to generate an image of rendered html than it is to just render html?

Comment: I can't use an image of that html. @robertc ,if I wanted to embed a youtube video, the video will not work.

Comment: In that cases you'll need to position the embedded content using CSS positioning.

Comment: so the best solution here  is to build a div positioning library that will link divs to graphical objects?

Comment: You're taking this whole approach for performance reasons, I'm asking you how you're expecting to gain that performance with this approach.

Comment: when using the canvas instead of the SVG can gain the wanted performance. because I show only one html content at a time, it wont be a major problem, though making it could be hard...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas), which renders a DOM in Canvas.

> I'm building a web UI.

I'm going to try and save us both trouble and let you know that **building an entire UI in Canvas is a really bad idea.** I'd advise against this. Heavily. And so would the canvas specification. [As the spec says:](https://developers.whatwg.org/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element)

> Authors should avoid implementing text editing controls using the canvas element. Doing so has a large number of disadvantages:
>
> - Mouse placement of the caret has to be reimplemented.
> - Keyboard movement of the caret has to be reimplemented (possibly across lines, for multiline text input).
> - Scrolling of the text field has to be implemented (horizontally for long lines, vertically for multiline input).
> - Native features such as copy-and-paste have to be reimplemented.
> - Native features such as spell-checking have to be reimplemented.
> - Native features such as drag-and-drop have to be reimplemented.
> - Native features such as page-wide text search have to be reimplemented.
> - Native features specific to the user, for example custom text services, have to be reimplemented. This is close to impossible since each user might have different services installed, and there is an unbounded set of possible such services.
> - Bidirectional text editing has to be reimplemented.
> - For multiline text editing, line wrapping has to be implemented for all relevant languages.
> - Text selection has to be reimplemented.
> - Dragging of bidirectional text selections has to be reimplemented.
> - Platform-native keyboard shortcuts have to be reimplemented.
> - Platform-native input method editors (IMEs) have to be reimplemented.
> - Undo and redo functionality has to be reimplemented.
> - Accessibility features such as magnification following the caret or selection have to be reimplemented.

Implementing these sorts of things in Canvas is a *nightmare*. For both you and your users.

Comment: so the floating div is the best solution here?